# React without a build step

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was looking at this article where this guy sets up react without having a build step. But he does it by getting rid of jsx. 
https://shinglyu.github.io/web/2016/04/06/minimal_react.html

But I want to keep jsx. I saw there's a jsfiddle that manages to run the jsx without having to do a build step:
https://jsfiddle.net/hganz/gk9kaopr/

```
var App = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
    return (
        <div>
        <h3>Todo List:</h3>
        <TodoListContainer />
        <TodoFormContainer />
      </div>
     );
  }
 });
```

But how does this work. Doesn't jsx need to be compiled to javascript code? Or is this jsfiddle using some kind of special library to do so. And if that's the case, why did the author that wrote the article on "minimal react" not use that.

Answer (score 0):

[JSX is just a synthetic sugar for React.createElement.](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html)
As for the jsfiddle you provided, [it uses the babel polyfill](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-polyfill/6.13.0/polyfill.js) as an external resource.
I guess that's the build step you were missing.

[image]

Comment: I thought babel is just for es6 related stuff. but how does that jsfiddle convert the jsx at runtime...

Comment: As i said, jsx is just another way to do `React.createElement`. So the jsx is handled by the react libraries that are also included in the fiddle as you can see in the screenshot.

Comment: By the way, babel also has a [react preset](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-react/) to handle jsx and more